# MySQL 5.5 Query Based on IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, phpmyadmin, procedure, case-statement

I've been battling with this for too long so I'm here to ask for help...

I have a MySQL stored procedure that I want to do the following:

given an 'id' and a 'username' for a given record

1. if id does not exist in table then create record
2. else if id exists and username is not the same as what exists then update record
3. else do nothing

I've tried the following:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE doCreate INT;
DECLARE doUpdate INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO doCreate FROM app_user WHERE id=1;
IF (doCreate > 0) THEN 
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO doUpdate FROM app_user WHERE id=1 AND username='other';
END IF

IF(doCreate = 0) THEN ---SYNTAX ERROR ON THIS LINE---
   SELECT 'CREATE';
ELSE IF(doUpdate = 0) THEN
   SELECT 'UPDATE';
ELSE
   SELECT 'NOTHING';
END IF

END
```

I've also tried replacing the if-elseif-else block with a case statement but get the same result...

```
CASE ---ERROR ON THIS LINE---
   WHEN doCreate = 0 THEN 
      SELECT 'CREATE';
   WHEN doUpdate = 0 THEN
      SELECT 'UPDATE';
   ELSE
      SELECT 'NOTHING';
END
```

- I seem to get a syntax error on anything that comes after the first END IF, so that's the first problem that occurs...

Any help would be appreciated - I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be to use `INSERT (id,username) INTO app_user VALUES ({id},{username}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UDPATE username = VALUES(username)`.

Comment: Vatev, I think with your solution it will always perform an update if the id exists. I DONT want it to perform an update if all the fields are already identical.

Comment: Yes, it will. I thought i should suggest it since it does a similar thing to your stored proc in a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to terminate the `END IF`s with `;`, and internally `ELSEIF` should be one word. Otherwise, another `END IF` is needed, but not found.

```
IF (doCreate > 0) THEN 
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO doUpdate FROM app_user WHERE id=1 AND username='other';
END IF; /* terminate with ; */

IF(doCreate = 0) THEN 
   SELECT 'CREATE';
ELSEIF(doUpdate = 0) THEN
   SELECT 'UPDATE';
ELSE
   SELECT 'NOTHING';
END IF; /* terminate with ; */
```

Look over the [MySQL `IF/ELSE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) for various usage examples.

Comment: Thanks!.. that did seem to get rid of the initial syntax error... however I am getting one on the last line now (at END).

Comment: ELSEIF ... one word :) Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Cailen Yes, I didn't notice the `ELSEIF`. Otherwise, it expects another `END IF` in there which isn't found.